# Using private_pub gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, private-pub

I wanted to use private_pub gem to follow along with this screencast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

However, when I run `rails g private_pub:install`, I get this error `Could not find hiredis-0.3.2 in any of the sources`.

Running bundle install install most of the dependencies, however, gives  `fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory` when trying install hiredis.

So, how do I use private_pub in windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Could not find hiredis-0.3.2 is any of the sources
```

- Windows 7

There is no support of hiredis on Windows (as of this answer). You can take a look at the pull requests for Windows at the [github repo for hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis)

- https://github.com/redis/hiredis/pull/52
- https://github.com/redis/hiredis/pull/139
- https://github.com/redis/hiredis/pull/48

With respect to your private_pub gem - the comment on the railscast video shows the [issue has been occuring for quite](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub?view=comments#comment_155628) some time on windows

Answer (score 0):

I can use `private_pub` on windows.
I did it a long ago, but I run `private_pub` with:

```
bundle exec private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
```

It only works with ruby 1.9.2. I had no success with 1.9.3.